# Does updating vzctl and ploop require server reboot?

Tags: openvz, ploop

If we yum update vzctl and ploop on centOS 6, 64-bit, does that require we reboot the server, or stop and start all containers? Just trying to understand if a normal yum update for these two software applications require additional steps as these seem to modify the normal operation of containers. Is it safe to just yum update them with running containers? Looking for best practices here...

We use ksplice for auto updates of the kernel, so the kernel is patched to the latest stable version without a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **it do NOT require host node reboot**. I risked and did

```
# yum update vzctl
```

It updated `vzctl` and `ploop` to new versions (verified with `vzctl --version`).

Containers remained running without issues and stopping/starting CTs works OK. I spotted small issue as a result of the update, [here are](http://internetlifeforum.com/virtualisation/4046-openvz-centos-7-new-os-templates-networking-do-not-works-fix-update-vzctl/) details.